# Assertion failure and NSInternalInconsistencyException when trying to run two functions simultaneously

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I've got two functions I'd like to run at the same time - show_video() and gesture_control(). The first reads in images from a camera stream and plots them using matplotlib. The second hooks up a few API's so that certain events are triggered based on objects detected in the video stream. I saw in a tutorial that I can run both functions simultaneously as follows:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target = show_video).start()
    Thread(target = gesture_control).start()
```

But I get all kinds of errors...

```
2017-08-04 14:39:05.072 python[9512:693356] WARNING: nextEventMatchingMask should only be called from the Main Thread! This will throw an exception in the future.
2017-08-04 14:39:05.072 python[9512:693356] *** Assertion failure in +[NSUndoManager _endTopLevelGroupings], /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Foundation/Foundation-1349.25/Misc.subproj/NSUndoManager.m:363
2017-08-04 14:39:05.075 python[9512:693356] *** Assertion failure in +[NSUndoManager _endTopLevelGroupings], /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Foundation/Foundation-1349.25/Misc.subproj/NSUndoManager.m:363
2017-08-04 14:39:05.077 python[9512:693356] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+[NSUndoManager(NSInternal) _endTopLevelGroupings] is only safe to invoke on the main thread.'

*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffa45580db __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fffb91dfa2a objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffa455cc32 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fffa5fc5d50 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 195
    4   Foundation                          0x00007fffa5f503f3 +[NSUndoManager(NSPrivate) _endTopLevelGroupings] + 170
    5   AppKit                              0x00007fffa1ff4047 -[NSApplication run] + 1200
+50 more rows

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: were you able to solve the issue?